# Is this bad? Better ways of doing this in Objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making an iphone app. All you need to know is that there is a main class called ArcherClass, and there is a class called Player.

in the Player class, this is how I set up different body parts (I created a stick figure, and parts of his body move seperately so I created a class just for the stick figure).

**Player.h**___*_*__

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Player : CCLayer {
    CGPoint position;
    float angle;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint *position;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint *angle;

+(id)player;

+(id)bow;
+(id)setHead;
+(id)setBody;
+(id)setLeftArm1;
+(id)setLeftArm2;
+(id)setRightArm1;
+(id)setRightArm2;
-(void)setAngles:(float)angle;

@end
```

This is the entire header file, later I plan on implementing all this inside the .m file.
But just so that I could give a general idea of what I'm asking, here is part of the unfinished .m file:

**Player.m_*_*__*_*___**

```
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

@synthesize position = _position;
@synthesize angle = _angle;

+(id)player{

    Player *playerSprite = nil;
    return playerSprite;
}

+(id)arm{
    Player *playerSprite = nil;
    playerSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"arm.png"];
    return playerSprite;
```

I plan on making all the Player's individual body parts this way.
Here is the main class's implementation:

**ArcherClass.m_*_*__*_*_**

```
//Skipped alot of stuff. Not the point.
Player *person = nil;
CCSprite *bob = [Player arm];
bob.position = ccp(160,160);
[self addChild:bob z:3];    
//above shows how I access the Person Class and use the function arm
```

I feel like I am doing this wrong. Is the way I've done this bad practice? Is there a better way of accessing a sprite in a different class and using it? Any feedback would be great, thanls.

Comment: To answer the very first part of the question: Yes. :)

Comment: The main problem is that most of your methods are class methods and not instance methods. So it's not really OOP but rather similar to using C functions and a struct to store some data.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D figures. Could you post an answer that will help me out? I'm still having problems with accessing the sprites and stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an OO perspective, that doesn't make sense.

This assumes ARC -- which you should be using for any new projects -- and, thus, the use of `strong` vs. `retain` (and no need for a `-dealloc` method).

Typically, you would do something like:

```
@interface Player : CCLayer
@property(strong) CCSprite *head;
@property(strong) CCSprite *rightArm;
... etc ...
@end
```

And then:

```
@implementation Player
@synthesize head, rightArm, ... etc ...;

- init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         head = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"head.png"];
         rightArm = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rightArm.png"];
         ... etc ....
    }
}
... etc ...
@end
```

You would then create an instance of the Player.  That instance would encapsulate all the sprites that compose the player, controlling position, etc.    You would then write method(s) such that you can move the player.  When the player moves, it should internally move all the parts to the appropriate spot.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. But what does this mean?       '@property(strong) CCSprite *head' ? What is strong? I've never seen that before

Comment: strong is synonymous with retain, it was introduced with Xcode 4.2 for use with ARC.

Comment: It doesn't work on my mac, and the computer/xcode version is relatively new

Comment: Did you turn on ARC in your code?  If the project is older than a few months.  Either go with MRR (use `retain` instead of `strong`) or convert the project to ARC (there is a menu item that does that).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends what exactly you want to do with your "stick figure", you haven't said. IOW specify the requirements then design the solution. Until there are requirements it is difficult to recommend approach A or approach B.

Comment: Well I would like approach B.

Comment: Just kidding, I'm going to individually move the sprite's angles/positions